# Rename files consecutively on two separate folders

Tags: linux, renaming

I have two folders, folderA with 50 files and folderB with lets say N files, what I need to do is this:
Rename all files from both folders with a common counter, everytime I rename a file from folderA, lets say 1, 3 files from folderB will get the consecutive counter number: 2, 3 and 4, and then go back to folderA and rename the next file with 5, until there are no files left on folderA.

folderA 1 5 9 13 17

folderB 2 3 4 6 7 8 10 11 12 14 15 16 18 19 20

Any thoughts?

Comment: This calls for a little programming. Do you know any programming languages?

Comment: I'm no programmer, but I've coded a little on C and some Linux scripts, but nothing related to managing files on different folders.

Comment: This solution could have been done in dozens of languages, so if you post a question like this it's best to give people an idea of what language you're wanting to use. The idea of this site is to help you learn, so it should be using a technology that you already have some familiarity with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code will do the trick. It is based on modulo to increment folderB numbers and an ad hoc stop condition if file count in folderB is more than 3 times the folderA file count.

- FolderA's pattern is 1, 5, 9... which is like initializing *i* to 1, and incrementing by 4 for each iteration.
- FolderB's incrementing name by 1 if *i modulo 4 is not 0* else it is incrementing by 2.

If copied-pasted into a file (let's say *renaming.sh*) and assuming proper execution permission ($> chmod +x renaming.sh), it could be used like that from the command line:

```
$> ./renaming.sh folderA folderB
```

Here's the code to put in the file:

```
#!/bin/bash


i=1
ACOUNT=0
for FILEA in $1/*; do
        mv "${FILEA}" "$1/${i}"
        (( i+=4 ))
        ((ACOUNT++))
done

i=1
BCOUNT=0
for FILEB in $2/*; do
        if (( i%4 )) ; then
                ((i++))
        else
                ((i+=2))
        fi
        if ((BCOUNT>= 3* ACOUNT)); then break; fi
        ((BCOUNT++))

        mv "${FILEB}" "$2/${i}"
done
```

Comment: @darko No problem. Please mark your question as resolved if it solves your problem: it makes things easier for others to find good answers. And tell me if it doesn't, we'll try to sort it out.